# Oil furnace cmf280-pg convertible problems

Tags: hvac

Cmf2 80-po convertible with a auto limit switch and a manual aux limit switch. Furnace will run a heat cycle to desired temp but then blower fan runs to cool furnace in 4 very short 3 second spurts. Then I believe it lockouts out to run another cycle ..have to turn thermostat way down or shut off for hours until it resets itself. Then will run this same cycle again and same problem

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What does [the manual](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Nordyne-Cmf2-80-Po-Convertible-8837126.html) say?

Comment: Manual does not show troubleshooting

Comment: How about the [installation manual](http://www.graycoolingman.com/uploads/1/0/6/6/10667336/nordyne_cmf2_80-pg_po_oil_and_gas_installation_instructions.pdf)?